# Which graduate program to pursue

Tags: statistics, recreational-mathematics

I just recently graduated with a Degree in Applied Mathematics and I am slightly confused as to which Masters Program I want to enter into. I will be applying to grad schools this Spring. I currently have a job right now as an inventory analyst at a corporate office and I do enjoy inventory but I am not sure I am "Passionate" about it. I have some computer programming knowledge (Python, R and C++) but I am not passionate about it.

I am thinking of either doing one of three options, 1) MS in Statistics 2) MS in Operations Research/logistics 3) MS in economics

1) I have a strong background in Statistics because of my applied math degree but want to do purely applications not proofs.

2) I love game theory and network problem and I enjoy how applicable it is to my current job, but what other careers can I get in operations research?

3) I love economics and econometrics (I almost majored in econ in college) but I am not sure which path this could lead me down.

I ultimately want a job where I can perform analytics and actually contribute my thoughts and see a project go from beginning to end and be able to say that "I did that".

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my personal choice of thinking that if you do MS in statstics then you always have road to go economics or optimization path which is not the case for other two.You have to stay in that particular field.So take your decision carefully .As long as  option in many institutes there is option of doing MS in stats with specalization in Economics or actuaries like that.So any way you can do that.Ask some expert from all field also that will be very useful.